# Second time clicking a button, app is crashing due to setcontentview

Tags: java, android, xml, onclicklistener, setcontentview

I'm getting an error which explains that requestFeature() must be called before adding content. And so I did just that, which made the dialog work when its clicked the first time, but i'm getting the same error when clicking on it the second time.

Logcat

```
     at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:5664)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6877) 
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26069) 
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374) 
         Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:385)
            at uk.co.controlf1.notifyv2.ShortCodeActivity.ShowPopup(ShortCodeActivity.java:197)
```

ShowPopup method

```
    public void ShowPopup(View v) {

        myDialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.more_info_dialog);
        txtclose = myDialog.findViewById(R.id.txtclose);





        txtclose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        myDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        myDialog.show();

    }
```

Main xml

```
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/errorMessage"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/submitShortCodeBtn"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="Please enter a value"
        android:textColor="#084c5c"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_ic_info"
        android:layout_width="13dp"
        android:layout_height="13dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/errorMessage"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/errorMessage"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/errorMessage"
        android:backgroundTint="#fff"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_info"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:onClick="ShowPopup"
        />
```

Dialog xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_background"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtclose"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:textColor="#084c5c"
    android:text="X"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/more_info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="More Info"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/shortcode_question"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:text="What is a shortcode?"
                android:textColor="#084c5c"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/shortcode_answer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/shortcode_question"
                android:text="A shortcode is...."
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/forgot_pass_question"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/shortcode_answer"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="What if I have forgot my shortcode?"
                android:textColor="#084c5c"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/forgot_pass_answer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/forgot_pass_question"
                android:text="Contact..."
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/internet_question"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/forgot_pass_answer"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Why do I need an internet connection?"
                android:textColor="#084c5c"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/internet_answer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/internet_question"
                android:text="You need an internet connection to..."
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/support_question"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/internet_answer"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Why do I need an internet connection?"
                android:textColor="#084c5c"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/suport_answer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/support_question"
                android:text="You need an internet connection to..."
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>




</RelativeLayout>
```

I am setting the onclick in my main xml, not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: try setting your onclick listener for btn_ic_info in your Activity and not on the xml file

Comment: @NikosHidalgo have tried, but same error